# Apply image Filters with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I want to apply an image filter using Fabric.js but I'm unable to. I'm a beginner with Fabric, but here is the code which I'm currently using:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mon_canvas');
         
            fabric.Image.fromURL('img/appart.jpg', function(img) {
       img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Sepia());
      img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
      canvas.add(img);
   });
  });
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="mon_canvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:1px dotted black;"></canvas>
  <img src="img/appart.jpg" id="my-image" style="visibility:hidden;">
   
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="fabricJS/dist/fabric.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have also imported the following scripts: 
fabricJS/dist/fabric.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: what is your exact problem? I mean, what error are you having? Try changing the first attribute in `fabric.Image.fromURL` and instead of the image path, pass the `document.getElementById('my-image');`

Comment: I tried what you told me to do but nothing appears on my page HTML !!! that's  my pb.

Comment: no errors in the javascript console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
fabric.util.loadImage @ fabric.js:592
fabric.Image.fromURL @ fabric.js:17555
(anonymous function) @ index.html:20
i @ jquery.min.js:2
j.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
n.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2
J @ jquery.min.js:2

Comment: I don't know why fabric.Image.fromURL(...)  is an anonymous function for my page HTML.Do I have to implement an other script on my page. the only tutorial that i found is :http://fabricjs.com/  have you other sources where i can read about this library. thanks @Mikel for helping me I appreciate

Comment: I've finally found the answer ,well there is no pb with my code i found that it has a relation 
with security with canvas elements for more details check this link https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#security-with-canvas-elements  ; i had to put my project 
on localhost (personnelly i use wampserver and it works for me )